# q difference between then with 2 functions and then followed by catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Just a quick clarification question:

is there any difference between

```
promiseGeneratingFunction.then(successHandler, errorHandler).done();
```

and

```
promiseGeneratingFunction.then(successHandler).catch(errorHandler).done();
```

?

Thanks

Comment: depends on what library you are using

Comment: @monkeyinsight [tag:q]

Comment: Why the `.done()` at the end?

Comment: @jfriend00 done handles any uncaught errors

Comment: @sakekasi there are promise libraries that allow you to omit the `.done` just so you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, those two examples are different.

The other answers are not considering the effects of chaining. The docs say:

```
A sugar method, equivalent to promise.then(undefined, onRejected).
```

So yes, `.catch` is equivalent to `.then`. But that isn't what your examples show.

You compare

```
promiseGeneratingFunction.then(successHandler, errorHandler).done();

// VS

promiseGeneratingFunction.then(successHandler).catch(errorHandler).done();
```

If we break the second example down using the documented comparison, it is actually:

```
promiseGeneratingFunction.then(successHandler, errorHandler).done();

// VS

promiseGeneratingFunction.then(successHandler).then(undefined, errorHandler).done();
```

Those two behave differently in how they handle errors. Both examples will call `successHandler` if the generated promise succeeds, and call `errorHandler` if the promise fails, so they are very similar. The difference comes from how they handle errors in `successHandler`.

```
// this is a fulfilled promise since the thrown error was handled
Promise.resolve().then(function(){ throw new Error(); }).catch(function(){});

// this is a rejected promise
Promise.resolve().then(function() { throw new Error() }, function(){});
```

If your `successHandler` function were to throw an exception (or return a rejected promise), your first example has no error handler attached (`errorHandler` is only attached to `promiseGeneratingFunction`, so your promise will throw an uncaught exception from the `.done()`. On the second example, the error thrown from `successHandler` would also be caught in `errorHandler` since it is bound farther down the promise chain.

The equivalent synchronous code is something like this:

```
var error = null;
var result;

try {
    result = func();
} catch (err){
    error = err;
}

if (error){
    errorHandler(error);
} else {
    successHandler(result);
}

// VS

try {
    var result = func();

    successHandler(result);
} catch (err){
    errorHandler(err);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I find the fact the other answer has two upvotes as really surprising. +1 for correctness and synchronous code analogy.

Answer (score -2):

> Q promises provide a fail shorthand for then when you are only interested in handling the error

As said documentation, it's only shorthand